# Build a QImage from a buffer

Tags: c++, image, qt, buffer, qimage

How I can build a QImage from a buffer for example?
In this case I'm using a buffer of 3x3 with vale from 0 (black) to 255 (white).

0   255 0
255 0   255
0   255 0

and it is store into a `unsigned char buffer[9] = {0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0};`

At the moment I'm trying this but doesn't work:

```
QImage image{buffer, 3, 3, QImage::Format_Grayscale8};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor you're using...

```
QImage(uchar *data, int width, int height, QImage::Format format, QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = nullptr, void *cleanupInfo = nullptr)
```

has the caveat...

> data must be 32-bit aligned, and each scanline of data in the image
> must also be 32-bit aligned

Hence the `QImage` implementation expects the number of bytes in each scanline to be a multiple of 4 -- a condition not satisfied by your data buffer.  Instead make use of the [constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#QImage-5) that allows you to specify the bytes-per-scanline explicitly...

```
QImage(uchar *data, int width, int height, int bytesPerLine, QImage::Format format, QImageCleanupFunction cleanupFunction = nullptr, void *cleanupInfo = nullptr)
```

So your code becomes...

```
unsigned char buffer[9] = {0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0};
QImage image{buffer, 3, 3, 3, QImage::Format_Grayscale8};
```